Deploying django app using almalinux 8 plesk
Recently i have created a website using django. But when it is time for deploying it became a nightmare. I am pretty new in these stuff. Since this is a productuon promissed for someone else i have to do it done. I wonder if anyone could do it for me?
I have a vps server running using plesk panel. And an almalinux 8 as os.
Any help would absolutely work.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Install docker extension in your plesk.  In your computer create a container for docker with your app. If this work in your machine upload container to your server.
I think this video can help you. https://youtu.be/PYN7sxfZWIo?si=ET_AzUnMJBDuUiEV
